# ILNumerics equivalent of MatLab/Octave statement

Tags: c#, matlab, octave, nan, ilnumerics

### Question

In `MatLab/Octave`, I have the statement `x(isnan(x)) = 0`.  I am porting this over to `ILNumerics` in `C#`.  I am having trouble finding the `ILNumerics` equivalent to the `MatLab/Octave` statement mentioned.

In our case, `x` is a `2x2` array.

### What we've tried

1. `noNaNDataValues = dataValues[ILMath.isnan(dataValues)] = 0.0;` where `dataValues` is an `ILArray<double>`
2. We have resorted to standard `C#` for loops and that works fine.  But we would rather use `ILNumerics` considering how much we've invested in it already.

Comment: What is wrong with `x[isnan(x)] = 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
x[isnan(x)] = 0;
```

This is directly equivalent to Matlabs syntax. Your first attempt suggests that you want to seperate non-NaN values from NaNs? If so, please clarify.

Comment: It was a silly mistake on our part.  Removing `noNaNDataValues = ...` from the first thing we tried fixed it.  The original error was an exception being thrown when trying no access a disposed object.

`{"Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'The storage is disposed already. Make sure to follow the ILNumerics documentation at http://ilnumerics.net/GeneralRules.html'."}`